# Log file not generated in dropwizard

Tags: java, logging, dropwizard

I have following log scheme. I want to rotate logs every 4 hours. But when I start application with these settings, `./logs/mylogs.log` file is not generated. I have `logs` directory created in application's directory.

It works fine if I change filename pattern to include minute as well like - 
`archivedLogFilenamePattern: ./logs/mylogs-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm}.log.gz`
I am confused why it does not work for hourly pattern?

```
logging:
  level: WARN
  appenders:
    - type: console
      threshold: WARN
    - type: file
      threshold: WARN
      logFormat: "%-6level [%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%t] %logger{5} - %X{code} %msg %n"
      currentLogFilename: ./logs/mylogs.log
      archive: true
      archivedLogFilenamePattern: ./logs/mylogs-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh}.log.gz
      archivedFileCount: 4
```

Using dropwizard 1.3.7

Comment: But `./logs/mylogs.log` *is* below the application directory. What do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropwizard uses [Logback](https://logback.qos.ch/) for logging. The rolling policy used here is [TimeBasedRollingPolicy](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#TimeBasedRollingPolicy).

The fileNamePattern to rollover at the beginning of every hour:

```
  archivedLogFilenamePattern: ./logs/mylogs-%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log.gz
```

Not sure if there is a way to rollover every n hours. You might want to consider using [FixedWindowRollingPolicy](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#FixedWindowRollingPolicy), which dropwizard supports. This will allow you to rollover based on size. Eg -

```
  - type: file
    threshold: ALL
    maxFileSize: 100MB
    currentLogFilename: ./logs/max-file-size-example.log
    archivedLogFilenamePattern: ./logs/max-file-size-example-%i.log.gz
    archivedFileCount: 5
```

Comment: I changed archivedLogFilenamePattern to the one you suggested, it is working as expected now.